# ODBC data connection on windows service

Tags: web-services, windows-services, odbc, windows-server-2008, database-connection

I have a console application that connects to a database through a ODBC connection, running on a windows server 2008. When I copy the exact same code into a web service, it doesn't work. Why is this/ what can I do to fix it?

Code is:

```
string connectStringGems = "DSN=GF4D;UID=Admin;PWD=pword";

string getInfo = "Select RUC_Expiry from vehicles where rego = '" + rego + "'";

OdbcDataAdapter daGems = new OdbcDataAdapter(getInfo, connectStringGems);

DataSet ds = new DataSet();

daGems.Fill(ds, "GemsUpdate");//The error is here I believe

DataTable dt = ds.Tables["GemsUpdate"];

DataRow row = dt.Rows[0];

use row etc....
```

Any ideas on what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You are probably using a [User DSN](http://digital.ni.com/public.nsf/allkb/852559036FB6447380256ADF007C3964) which is only accessible by the user who created it. Try either:

- Using a system DSN
- Configuring your [service to login as the user](http://www.coretechnologies.com/WindowsServices/FAQ.html#AppNotWorkingFromService) who created the DSN